# Flutter App give blank page in the emulator

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm running this code in my Flutter app

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}



class  App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Titolo",
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Posizionamento')),
        body: Container(
          child: Text('LOGIN')
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

When I run "flutter run" in terminal, it gives a blank page in the emulator.
What's wrong?

Comment: Your Code works. The issue must be with your emulator/setup

Comment: try deleting the app and running flutter clean

Comment: Not even app bar ?